# PostgreSQL statement timeout error on a function when "statement_timeout = 0"

Tags: postgresql, timeout

I'm using [PGWatch2](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pgwatch2) monitoring for a master(write) and two replication(read) servers. This monitoring uses [this function](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pgwatch2/blob/master/pgwatch2/metrics/stat_statements/9.4/metric.sql) to get query information. There is no errors on master server but replications have this error:

```
pgwatch2@database ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
pgwatch2@database STATEMENT:  
        with q_data as (
          select
    ...
```

This query takes about 7s on master and
both replication servers and master has `statement_timeout=0`:

```sh
 statement_timeout 
-------------------
 0
(1 row)
```

I'm using **PostgreSQL 12.9** on **UBUNTU 20.04.1**

Comment: Well, then probably the standbys have that parameter set differently.

Comment: As I mentioned before, that parameter is set to zero on both master and replications. Is this parameter applied to functions too?

Comment: Yes. Note that every session can change the parameter, and many ORMs and other frameworks set a non-zero limit by default.